# Save and restore unsaved buffers in neovim

Tags: session, neovim

Sublime Text keeps track of any unsafed changes in files when closing and rebooting it will reopen the unsafed changes.

I'm looking for something similar in Neovim. I had a look at `persistence.nvim`, auto-sessions, `sessions.nvim`. They are all great for saving/restoring sessions but if I have a buffer open with unsafed changes they will be lost on a unexpected neovim crash for example.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get this to work?

Comment: See `:help swap-file`